# Como funciona o objeto history Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber se existe limite de URLs a serem recuperadas ou não, ele tem acesso a todo o histórico ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O objeto de `history` contém os URLs visitados pelo usuário (dentro de uma janela do navegador). Ele faz parte do objeto `window` e é acessado através da propriedade `window.history`.

A propriedade `length` retorna o número de URLs na lista de histórico.

```
var num = window.history.length;
```

A propriedade `current` contém o URL completo da entrada atual do histórico.

```
var urlAtual = window.history.current
```

A propriedade `next` contém o URL completo do próximo elemento na lista histórico. É o mesmo que clicar em um botão *Avançar*.

```
var avancar = window.history.next
```

A propriedade `previous` contém o URL completo do elemento anterior na lista Histórico. É o mesmo que clicar em um botão *Voltar*.

```
var voltar = window.history.previous
```

Você pode usar um dos 3 métodos:

- `back()`: Carrega o URL anterior na lista do histórico. 
  `window.history.back();`
- `forward()`: Carrega o próximo URL na lista de histórico.
  `window.history.forward();`
- `go()`: Carrega um URL específico da lista de histórico.
  `window.history.go(-1);`

Uma observação sobre o `go()`, se você está em uma página e entra em uma outra página de cadastro, por exemplo, dentro dessa página de cadastro contém um botão voltar com um a propriedade `onclick="javascript:history.go(-1);"`, quando clicar no botão você será redirecionado a última página acessada antes da página cadastro.

HTML5 introduziu os métodos `history.pushState()` e `history.replaceState()`,  que permitem adicionar e modificar entradas do histórico, respectivamente. Esses métodos funcionam em conjunto com o evento [`window.onpopstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate).

Suponha que `http://mozilla.org/foo.html` executa o seguinte JavaScript:

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
```

Isso fará com que a barra de URL exiba `http://mozilla.org/bar.html`, mas não fará com que o navegador carregue `bar.html` ou mesmo verificar que `bar.html` existe.

`pushState()` possui três parâmetros: um `state object` (Sempre que o usuário navega para o novo estado, um evento `popstate` é disparado e propriedade `state` do evento contém uma cópia do objeto de estado da entrada de `popstate`), um `title` (Firefox atualmente ignora este parâmetro, embora possa usá-lo no futuro. Passar a string vazia aqui deve ser seguro contra futuras mudanças no método. Alternativamente, você poderia passar um título curto para o estado para o qual você está se movendo.) e (opcionalmente) um `URL` (O URL da nova entrada de histórico é dado por este parâmetro).

Obs: O objeto `state` pode ser qualquer coisa que possa ser serializado. Como o Firefox salva objetos de estado no disco do usuário para que possam ser restaurados após o usuário reiniciar o navegador, impomos um **limite de tamanho de 640k caracteres** na representação serializada de um objeto de estado. Se você passar um objeto de estado cuja representação serializada é maior do que isso para `pushState()`, o método lançará uma exceção. Se você precisar de mais espaço do que isso, você será encorajado a usar `sessionStorage` e/ou `localStorage`.

Além do primeiro script, suponha que `http://mozilla.org/foo.html` executa também este outro:

```
history.replaceState(stateObj, "page 3", "bar2.html");
```

Suponha agora que o usuário agora navega para `http://www.microsoft.com` e, em seguida, clica novamente. Neste ponto, a barra de URL exibirá `http://mozilla.org/bar2.html`. Se o usuário clicar novamente novamente, a barra de URL exibirá `http://mozilla.org/foo.html` e desviará totalmente `bar.html`.

O método `history.replaceState()` opera exatamente como `history.pushState()`, a diferença é que ele modifica a entrada de histórico atual em vez de criar uma nova. Observe que isso não impede a criação de uma nova entrada no histórico global do navegador. Esse método é útil quando você deseja atualizar o objeto de estado ou URL da entrada de histórico atual em resposta a alguma ação do usuário.

Fonte: [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_history.asp) e [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

Sobre a limitação, tem uma [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355549/window-history-length-maximum-value) parecido no stackoverflow em inglês, falando que o `window.history.length` não passa de 50. Um dos comentários diz que isso pode muito bem ser um limite específico do navegador. Segundo essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16358702/5327226), se você precisar que ele persista entre as sessões e sobreviva a uma limpeza das informações do usuário (cache, localStorage, etc.), você pode adotar soluções diferentes. Na resposta, o autor sugere esse código:

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    var count = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('history-changes-count'), 10);
    localStorage.setItem('history-changes-count', ++count);
};
```

Observe que [`onpopstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate) é invocado somente após uma ação do usuário, ele não funciona se você modificar o histórico programaticamente.

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com a **[W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp)** o método `history` tem acesso a todo o histórico do browser.

**Definition and Usage**

> The back() method loads the previous URL in the history list.

---

> O método `back()` carrega a URL anterior do histórico.

This is the same as clicking the "Back button" in your browser, or `history.go(-1)`.

---

Isso é o mesmo clicar no botão **Voltar** do Browser ou usar `history.go(-1)` - voltar uma página.

> Note: This method will not work if the previous page does not exist in the history list.

---

Nota: Este método não funcionará se a página anterior não existir no histórico.

Função que "desabilita" o botão **Voltar** do navegador.

```
(function (global) {
    if(global === undefined)
    {
        throw new Error("window is undefined");
    }

    var _hash = "!";
    var noBackPlease = function () {
        global.location.href += "#";

        global.setTimeout(function () {
            global.location.href += "!";
        }, 50);
    };

    global.onhashchange = function () {
        if (global.location.hash !== _hash) {
            global.location.hash = _hash;
        }
    };

    global.onload = function () {

        noBackPlease();

        document.body.onkeydown = function (e) {
            var elm = e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase();
            if (e.which === 8 && (elm !== 'input' && elm  !== 'textarea')) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }

            e.stopPropagation();
        };

    };

})(this.window);
```

Esse código acima funciona, mas se o usuário clicar com o botão direito em cima do botão **Voltar** do browser e escolher um item do histórico a função não previne.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção. Certo, mas o que é levado em consideração o momento em que abro o navegador e tenho acesso a partir dessa sessão, ou todo o histórico mesmo ? E existe uma forma de não permitir esse acesso pelo navegador ?

Comment: A função tem acesso ao histórico todo na sessão. Se você abrir o navegador que tem um botão com essa função, não irá voltar para lugar nenhum. Porque na sessão nova que você abriu, ainda não tem um histórico.

Comment: Ufa, essa era minha dúvida... É na sessão só...